# Joining a JSONArray adds double quotes to the string in groovy

Tags: json, grails, join, groovy, arrays

I have grails app that makes a REST call. If an error occurs, a JSON array containing the error messages is returned. I need to combine these strings into a single string. However, when I do so double quotes are added to the front and end of the string. I have written a simple test controller to illustrate the problem:

```
import net.sf.json.*
class MyController {

    def test = {

        String msg = "'fred' is not a valid LDAP distinguished name."
        JSONArray messages = new JSONArray()
        messages.add(msg)
        def renderStr = messages.join('<br/>')

        render(renderStr)
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
"'fred' is not a valid LDAP distinguished name."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the join function returns JSON-spec strings... which, according to their documentation here: http://grails.org/doc/1.0.3/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/json/JSONArray.html

```
 The texts produced by the toString methods strictly conform to JSON syntax rules. The constructors are more forgiving in the texts they will accept:

    An extra , (comma) may appear just before the closing bracket.
    The null value will be inserted when there is , (comma) elision.
    Strings may be quoted with ' (single quote).
    Strings do not need to be quoted at all if they do not begin with a quote or single quote, and if they do not contain leading or trailing spaces, and if they do not contain any of these characters: { } [ ] / \ : , = ; # and if they do not look like numbers and if they are not the reserved words true, false, or null.
    Values can be separated by ; (semicolon) as well as by , (comma).
    Numbers may have the 0- (octal) or 0x- (hex) prefix.
    Comments written in the slashshlash, slashstar, and hash conventions will be ignored.
```

Note that the rule that "Strings do not need to be quoted at all **if they do not begin with a quote or single quote**" is what's happening.  Your string starts with a quote, so if it was output without quotes, a JSON parser would assume the string ended at the 2nd single-quote, and the text afterwards would be unparseable garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Use this handy method

```
private String joinJSONArray(arr, delim = ',') {
    def result = ''

    arr.eachWithIndex { e, i ->
        result += e

        if (i != arr.size() - 1) {
            result += delim
        }
    }

    result
}
```

It makes use of `eachWithIndex` as Groovy doesn not provide a `injectWithIndex`.